# Spark Structured Streaming Kafka Integration Offset management

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The documentation says:

> enable.auto.commit: Kafka source doesn’t commit any offset.

Hence my question is, in the event of a worker or partition crash/restart :

1. startingOffsets is set to latest, how do we not loose messages  ?
2. startingOffsets is set to earliest, how do we not reprocess all messages ?

This is seems to be quite important. Any indication on how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into this issue.

You're right in your observations on the 2 options i.e.

- potential data loss if `startingOffsets` is set to `latest`
- duplicate data if `startingOffsets` is set to `earliest`

However...

There is the option of checkpointing by adding the following option:

`.writeStream
.<something else>
.option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/HDFS/dir")
.<something else>`

In the event of a failure, Spark would go through the contents of this checkpoint directory, recover the state before accepting any new data.

I found [this useful reference](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-structured-streaming-part-7/) on the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess it would be nice if the official doc could say what is being saved. I guess the last offsets processed per partition ?

Comment: I can't really remember the details as it was a while ago. But you're right - this info should be in the documentation and it is hard to find.. :)

Comment: You're welcome @Victor. I'm glad you found it useful. :)