# How do I implement offset management in Spark streaming with Kafka inside Spark itself?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have to implement offset management within Spark for a streaming job in Java which reads from a Kafka stream. However, though the process has been described in the official documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html), it does not actually give a code example of how to actually store and retrieve offsets from checkpoints. Rather, it cryptically says that

> If you enable Spark checkpointing, offsets will be stored in the checkpoint.

Does this mean that if I just provide the checkpoint directory to the Spark context, it would automatically store offsets? What about retrieval of the last offset read when the application comes back on? The [detail page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) on checkpointing that is linked there also leaves everything to the reader and only gives the syntax to set the checkpoint destination.

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-spark-data-pipeline) and [this](https://objectpartners.com/2016/10/13/analyzing-kafka-data-streams-with-spark/) give some clue as to how to use checkpoints, but in all of the instances, I can find that they have been used to cumulatively calculate something and not to store offsets. 
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342947/spark-structured-streaming-kafka-integration-offset-management) comes close, but still does not describe it.

Please help me in realizing this goal.

Comment: If we restart spark streaming application, it reads the check point directory   what ever data stored in checkpoint directory accessed and processed.

Comment: If you read more - checkpoints don't work if you upgrade the code... Better to use Zookeeper or Kafka itself for Offset management

Comment: I am trying to save offsets in Kafka. But how do I retrieve the latest offset, so that I can resume processing from the record that was last processed?

Answer (score 0):

Saving Offsets in checkpoint does not work for you, because spark will save tasks in the check point so up-gradation of the code requires to delete the checkpoint. Instead you can save the offsets in Zookeeper,Kafka,File-System or any database.

Comment: I am trying to save offsets in Kafka. But how do I retrieve the latest offset, so that I can resume processing from the record that was last processed?